# How did Root find out about the Machine and Finch?

Tags: plot-explanation, person-of-interest

How was Root able to understand that the Machine exists in the first place in *Person of Interest*?

I can't remember that it was revealed in any episode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember how good Root was as a hacker. It was when she hacked into Team Finch's private network through a honeypot network in episode 13 of season 1: [Root Cause](https://personofinterest.fandom.com/wiki/Root_Cause)

> "Wait, something's wrong. We didn't hack in, we were let in. It's a
> honeypot! Incredibly sophisticated... they're using a worm to infect
> any devices connected to our private network, including our phones.
> They're listening to us right now, destroy your phone. You know how to
> find me." (Finch)

[Root](https://personofinterest.fandom.com/wiki/Root):

> ....Root briefly hacks into Finch's network by creating a
> honeypot, presumably learning about Finch and The Machine in the
> process.